# Twilio, get audio from text

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I'm using NodeJS to interact with Twilio functions, now I want to get a speech from text.

Here is the process:

1. The client write its message in a text box.
2. A clickable button is there so that when the client clicks it the speech of the text is returned.

I want to know if this functionality exists? And if it's yes what is it then?

Comment: I don't think you can get the speech as MP3 or something, if that's what you mean (other than by maybe sending a request to `https://www.twilio.com/console/voice/api/twiml/text-to-speech/media?locale=en-US&provider=Amazon%20Polly&text=Hello%20World&voice=Salli` with the cookies from your Twilio console login session, since that option exists in the admin console for testing voices, but that's not an officially supported way of course)

Comment: Inside a call, you can return the `<Say>` TwiML verb though, to send the speech to the other party on the line.

Comment: A very roundabout way (not sure if it's worth it) would be to create a phone conference with nobody in it, enable recording of the conference, `<Say>` the thing, close the conference, wait for the MP3 of the recording to be available and download the recording.